# QGIS Clip doesn't work

Tags: qgis, shapefile, clip

I am using QGIS and I simple want to clip a shape with another shape but the result isn't right - the result is only that what you see in my screenshot. What can I do?

Picture 1: Shape 1

Picture 2: Shape 2

Picture 3: Result

[image: Shape 1]
[image: Shape 2]
[image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

You may have topology errors.
Tri to fix it with the processing tool called "Fix geometries" in QGIS 3.2